# Using google maps as a background?

Tags: php, html, css, api, google-maps

Okay so I have tried to implement Google Maps as a background to my website. But when I try to put text over it using this code:

```
.content{
z-index:0;
background-color:fffff;
position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
width: 900;
height: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

And that is giving me an error with the map it is displaying it on top of the map, which is what I want but it is not working with with margins for some reason. All my code is here: http://pastebin.com/uz6wwtYZ

Can anyone help me because I want the content in the center of the webpage and the map to act as the background.

Thanks.

Comment: I really don't recommend this approach, as it's bound to run up against Google's limits on free map use sooner or later.

Comment: But If i want to how could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adjusting the top and left instead of margin when an item is set to an absolute position:

```
.content{
z-index: 100;
background-color:fffff;
position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 100px;
width: 900;
height: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

Hope that helps? Also might want to set a higher z-index value as I have done above.

If you want it horizontally centered with auto margin values but also absolutely positioned, I don't think you can do that.

You can try this instead by giving your content an absolute width and offsetting the left property:

```
    .content{
width: 500px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color:fffff;
    position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 50%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
margin-left: -250px; /* half the value of the width */
    }
```

Here's a link to a JS Fiddle that uses your code:  http://jsfiddle.net/4FLKt/1/ Seems to be working fine.

Mikey.

Comment: Well the problem is that with taht it doesn't allow my website to be centered no matter what. I want it to act the same as this: harrisonbh.com/lrch

Comment: Well it should do just that, did you even try the code? What happened? More specific feedback will help us on your problem.

Comment: It is working to a certain extent but its not working like the content in: harrisonbh.com/lrch

Comment: @user1876032 Try my second snippet now. I took out the second width which may have interfered with it.

Comment: I updated mine and it seems to work a little better. Check out this though: https://gist.github.com/4251552 Its only displaying the background partially.

Comment: Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/4FLKt/ You forgot to add "px" to the width. Also, you need to offset any padding too.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your using `position: absolute;` and that is not working togetter with `margin:auto;`.

Place a div around it with a full width over the google maps and make that absolute... then in that div you can center a other div.

**Example**

```
<div> //This div has position:absolute; and the width of the Google maps chart.
  <div> //This div has margin:0 auto;
     Content here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay so some thing like: <div>Google Stuff thats absolut <div>content that uses margins here?</div></div> I'm not sure what the code should look like. Can you give an example please?

Comment: But where in that would i place the source code for the map and the map div. Look in the paste bin.

Comment: first of your map div is closed directly... this will give problems : <div id="map"></div>.... and you need to keep the map as it is... this div is placed at the place where the content div is right now.

Comment: So in the first <div> I would give it: id="map"?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try putting the content on top of the map?

```
#map {
    z-index:1;
}
.content{
    z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have done that but no matter what the margins are interfearing with the position absolute. Should I just remove the position, or what?

Comment: Well i want it to work similar to this webite here: harrisonbh.com/lrch but instead of a back background use the map.

Comment: Oh. Put your content full width and have a div inside that has the margins.

Comment: See my answer, it will center your content div.

Comment: @user1876032 Have you thought about accepting an answer to this question? I'm not saying I deserve it, but it would be good to have clarification of what happened. It would be bad etiquette not to.

Comment: Yes i did accept your answer, but why comment under someone else's answer? Kinda misleading, but anyway thank you.