# Google map as background with centered columns

Tags: css, layout, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to do something similar to what's related in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804006/using-google-maps-as-a-background), which is having a Google Map as a background filling the whole page and then some content on top of it. But the difference is that I have a two columns layout for this content and I want it to be responsive, so I'm having a hard time centering it.

The problem is that the map needs to be functional, so I want to leave as much space as possible for it. I know the map below the two columns will not be functional but I want the rest to be.

If I use a wrapper to center the two columns, the wrapper sits on top of the map and this map area is no longer usable (can't drag, click, etc).

So what can I do to center both columns? I'm open to some JS if necessary though I'm quite newbie on it.

EDIT: I've made a [super sketch](http://i1279.photobucket.com/albums/y522/claraearendil/Blank_zpsbce80043.png) to try to help visualize... On it you can see how if I use a wrapper (the transparent violet layer) and center it (like I'm doing on the rest of the pages), it covers the center part of the map where the markers are.

Comment: Without having any insight into your application I would attempt a stab in the dark. Did you make sure that your map is top most by setting it's z-index? Some code examples will be helpful in assisting you.

Comment: @user65439 thanks for your attempt, I am working on a fiddle but it's pretty complex to reproduce all the grid and convert my sass to css for it. I've made a sketch, where you can see I can't make my map at the most top because I have the columns on top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see how you could have a completely functional map with content on top.  For the content to be visible, it will have to have a higher z-index, which will in turn cover up the elements in your map. You could set your 'map-canvas' as the body, and then position divs with content in areas around the map, but away from your POI's or the map control tools, and use an RGBA color for the background color of the content divs (maybe 50% opacity), but anything under that content will be out of reach for the visitor because of the div on top.

Something like this should get you started though...:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
       <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.248669, -80.804619),
          zoom: 15,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

 var markers = [];

markers[0] = new google.maps.Marker({
       icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|00E64D|000000',
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(35.247334, -80.805382),
    map: map
});

markers[1] = new google.maps.Marker({
       icon: 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=B|FF0000|000000',
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(35.247551, -80.804008),
    map: map
});


for ( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
      window.location.href = this.url;  //changed from markers[i] to this[i]
    });
}
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
  <style type="text/css">
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative; 
}
.content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#content1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 153, 153, 0.5);
    border: 2px solid #222;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 100px;
    z-index: 999;
}
#content2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(153, 110, 0, 0.41);
    border: 2px solid #222;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top: 400px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -350px;
    z-index: 999;
}
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px auto; position: relative; z-index: -1;">
    </div>
    <div id="content1">blah blah</div>
    <div id="content2">Fuu</div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

So to get your two columns, you will need to make #content1 and #content2 100% in height.  The problem is your map controls are on the sides, so you would have to adjust your positioning for this.  Look at the Google Maps API to see if you can change position of controls.  Maybe put both columns on the right, and turn off the control for satelite/map view and set the default for your desired effect.

I can see how this would be really cool with the 45 degree view and an initial zoom of 5 or so in a large city.

EDIT TO EXPLAIN ABSOLUTE POSITIONING:

Traditionally, a web page would have a containing div, usually .wrapper or .container, and all of your elements would go inside of that.  If fact, this example has just such a container, .wrapper.  However, if we tried to implement a wrapper for content overlaying the map, even though it would be transparent, it would overlay all map elements and prevent the user from having functionality of the map.  So we need to use absolute positioning.  Absolute positioning is "absolute" relative to the closest containing element with a position of "relative," in this case .wrapper.

Because absolute positioning will place your element (#content1, #content2)  based on the user's screen resolution, your results would be inconsistent if you used a strict placement definition such as pixels, ie:

```
#content2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

The above code would move the element #content2 100 pixels from the left, whatever your screen resolution.  In fact, this may be the right approach for your left sidebar, and would clear the Google Maps navigation tool so that a user could zoom the map.

However, you may wish for your content element to be centered, regardless of the screen resolution.  In order to achieve this, you would set left:50%; and then adjust with margins.  Setting left:50% centers the left-most part of the element in the middle of the screen, regardless of resolution.  Since the element has a width of 250px, setting margin-left: -125px; would move the element back to the left 50% of it's total width, thus centering the element.  If your width was 300px, you would set margin-left: -150px, and so on for centering.  Based on your drawing, I would guess you would want your content area to be around 650px, and more to the right rather than centered, so for the content div you could use this code:

```
#content1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 650px;
    height: 150px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px #000;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 153, 153, 0.5);
    border: 2px solid #222;
    border-radius: 15px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 180px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

I design most pages to have a width of 960 pixels minimum to cover the iPad.  If  I wanted to make sure #content1 would fit in the field of view, I would have to figure a screen width of 960 pixels, and divide that by two (480px) since our element's left edge is centered.  Since the element is 650 pixels, it would extend too far to the right (by 170 pixels).  So to put my content div #content1 where it would be near the middle of the page on a wide screen monitor (1920 pixels) and still completely visible on a smaller monitor such as an iPad, I would have to set margin-left: -180px.  This will give a comfortable 10px margin on the right side of the element when viewed on an iPad.

One further note of importance; I used the box-sizing: border-box; property.  This property makes sure that whatever designation I give for width (650px here), will be the total element width, including padding and border.  Without using border-box, my #content1 div would be 684px wide. (width:650px, padding 10px left and 10px right,  border 2px left and 2px right).  Using box-sizing: border-box makes my math simpler.

If you found my answer useful, please mark your question as answered by choosing my answer as correct.

Comment: thanks for your answer, could you please explain a little your css? I can't see how it's centering the two columns, is it the relation between `left`, `width`, and `margin-left`? I've edited my question and added a sketch if it helps visualize the idea...

Comment: thanks for your explanation but it's not working for me and I'm sure it's because of the way Foundation 4 manages the layouts, making rows and anything :after and :before display as a table. So if I don't do anything, my first column is centered by default, the problem is the second one...

Comment: @ithil I am not familiar with Foundation 4.  Your original question (before your update) was how to have a page with Google Maps as a fucntional background, with divs for content on top.  I feel like I have more than sufficiently answered your question, including full code examples.  Your issue with Foundation 4 goes beyond the scope of your original question, and should be a new question on SO.  SO questions are not meant to be an ongoing forum.  Please accept my answer regarding your Google Maps question and post a new one for F-4 so someone with expertise can help you on that issue. Thanks!

Comment: sure, so I'll leave the orignal question as it was and will try to get help in another question as suggested

Comment: Good luck, I hope you get it figured out.  I'm not a framework guy. (Wish I was sometimes.)